# First time when page load flexslider not Initialize

Tags: javascript

I am facing Issue can any body help me .
 Flexslider is working fine on dev/test/live server but on production server for the first time flexslider is not Initialize . I
have checked all structure is ready just that flexslider not
initialising. Javascript & CSS coming from CDN and we have used
 rocketscript to compress js .

Comment: Is there any error when you open firebug console?

Comment: in view page source, your js and css is loaded? (you will have to go to performance and uncheckmark aggregate css and js boxes, so you can see individually what is being loaded)

Comment: There is know error in firebug console. Let me try that option.

Comment: I have checked js is loading and css loading .second time it is working fine.Any body know that this may come through cloudfare or any varnish issue

Comment: Will it occur again when you clear all your browser cache?

Comment: Yes and after refresh page working fine

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. Anyone found the same issue and a possible solution?

And yes, it occurs again as it seems an issue with flexslider and caching